# Finding all invertible elements of $S^{-1}D$, $D$ is a Noetherian integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

Let $D$ be a Noetherian integral domain and let $S$ be a multiplicatively closed subset.
The saturation $\tilde{S}$ of $S$ is
the set of all divisors of elements of $S$.
Clearly,
$S^{-1}D = \tilde{S}^{-1}D$,
see [page 138](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/integral2015.pdf).

**My question:** Is it possible to find all the invertible elements of $S^{-1}D$
for a given $S$ and $D$?
Trivially, all the elements of $S \cup S^{-1}$ (more precisely, the group this set generates) are invertible in $S^{-1}D$, but what about other invertible elements?
For convenience, I do not mind to assume that $S$ is generated by one element only, denote it by $s$.

**A special case:** If $D$ is also a UFD, and $S= \{p^j\}_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$, where $p$ is a prime
element of $D$, then the invertible elements of $S^{-1}D$ are exactly
$\{p^j\}_{j \in \mathbb{Z}}$;
indeed, if $d_1/p^{a_1}$ is invertible, then
$(d_1/p^{a_1})(d_2/p^{a_2}) =1$, but then
$d_1 d_2 = p^{a_1+a_2}$, so $d_1=p^{b}$ for some
$0 \leq b \leq a_1+a_2$, hence $d_1/p^{a_1}= p^{b}/p^{a_1} =p^{b-a_1}$.

(Actually, a slightly generalized argument shows that in a Noetherian UFD, for every $\tilde{S}$  which is generated by $\{p_1,\ldots,p_m\}$, where $p_i$ are prime elements of $D$,
the invertible elements of $S^{-1}D= \tilde{S}^{-1}D$ are exactly
$ \{p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots p_m^{\alpha_m} \}_{\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_m \in \mathbb{Z}}$).

But what if $D$ is not a UFD? The assumption that $D$ is Noetherian guarantees that $s \in S \subset D$ can be written (in at least one way) as a product of irreducible elements,
but those irreducible factors may not be prime elements of $D$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $d\in D$ and $s\in S$, note that $\frac{1}{s}$ is invertible, so $\frac{d}{s}$ is invertible iff $d$ is invertible.  Now $\frac{e}{t}$ is an inverse to $d$ iff $de=t$.  So $d$ is invertible iff there exists $e\in D$ such that $de$ is an element of $S$.  That is, $d\in D$ is invertible iff $d\in\tilde{S}$.  Thus the invertible elements of $S^{-1}D$ are just the fractions whose numerator is in $\tilde{S}$.

Comment: Thank you very much! (The argument "note that $1/s$ is invertible" is not necessary?).

Comment: Well, to deduce that $ab$ is invertible knowing that $a$ is invertible, you need to know $b$ is invertible; I'm doing this with $a=d$ and $b=1/s$.  But you could just say that $d=\frac{d}{s}\cdot s$ to deduce the same thing (of course, this is just explicitly using the inverse of $1/s$).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.